# PCF Dev incompatible with CF CLI

Tags: cloud-foundry, pcfdev

I tried to install PCF Dev on my local machine, following the instructions given in the [PCF tutorial](https://pivotal.io/de/platform/pcf-tutorials/getting-started-with-pivotal-cloud-foundry-dev/install-the-cf-cli) by Pivotal.

I installed CF CLI successfully. But PCF dev complains that the suggested version of CF is too old.

```
human@mb:Users/human> cf --version
cf Version 6.42.0+0cba12168.2019-01-10
human@mb:Users/human> /tmp/pcfdev-v0.30.0+PCF1.11.0-osx
Your cf CLI version is too old. Please install the latest cf CLI.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking that the pcfdev cf cli plugin might no longer be compatible, but I ran the instructions on my laptop and it worked for me.

```
$ cf -v
cf version 6.42.0+0cba12168.2019-01-10

$ ./pcfdev-v0.30.0+PCF1.11.0-osx
Plugin successfully installed. Current version: 0.30.0. For more info run: cf dev help

$ cf plugins
Listing installed plugins...

plugin   version   command name   command help
pcfdev   0.30.0    dev, pcfdev    Control PCF Dev VMs running on your workstation
```

I would suggest you try the following:

1. Download the pcfdev cli plugin from PivNet again. Then run the following command and make sure your shasum matches exactly with what I have here.

   ```
   $ shasum -a 256 pcfdev-v0.30.0+PCF1.11.0-osx
   ff48a6d3ff80a7e4ad9e18d9e931d419b413251add5fa4dffe01ad8472982491  pcfdev-v0.30.0+PCF1.11.0-osx
   ```
2. Try a fresh CF_HOME. Run `export CF_HOME=~/.cf-new`, then try running `cf install-plugin /tmp/pcfdev-v0.30.0+PCF1.11.0-osx`. The cf cli should see `CF_HOME` and use that as the location where it writes config & stores plugins. This should guarantee no other plugins are conflicting. If this works, you can just delete `~/.cf` and `~/.cf-new` to clean everything up, unset CF_HOME and install the plugin one more time. Then you should be all set.
3. I didn't have any compatibility issues, so I can't say for sure, but you could always try installing an older version of the cf cli & see if that helps. The PCF Dev software is getting pretty old, so using an older cf cli could help (despite the error message you're getting).
4. Double check that you only have one cf cli version installed on your system. I'm not sure off hand how pcfdev finds the cf cli when you run it directly, but maybe it's finding some other version of the cf cli. Alternatively, you could run `cf install-plugin /tmp/pcfdev-v0.30.0+PCF1.11.0-osx`. It should do the same thing and you'll control which version of the cf cli is being used.

---

Alternatively, you might want to give cf-dev a try. It's newer and will end up giving you a newer version of Cloud Foundry, which is a good thing. It's still technically alpha software (at the time I write this), but if you're just using it for local dev work that's probably OK. Anyway, the install process is very similar and you can follow the instructions to get going here.

https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cfdev

Hope that helps!